# Something before csv header and how can i deal with it when i use serde in rust

Tags: csv, rust, serde

Before csv header(time,ampl), there are some 'invalid' data.

**the csv is about:**

LECROYWS3024,13568,Waveform

Segments,1,SegmentSize,100002

Segment,TrigTime,TimeSinceSegment1

#1,01-Apr-2021 16:49:34,0

Time,Ampl

-2.510018e-005,0

-2.509968e-005,0

-2.509918e-005,0

-2.509868e-005,0

-2.509818e-005,0

...

when i build and run the exe, then an error is occured as below :

**the error is :**

CSV deserialize error: record 1 (line: 1, byte: 29): missing field `Time`

How can I deal with the invalid data with serde or other crates? Thanks!

```
        use std::error::Error;
        use std::io;
        use std::process;
        
        use serde::Deserialize;
        
        #[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
        struct Record {
            Time: Option<f32>,
            Ampl:Option<f32>,
        }
        ...
fn example() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    let mut rdr = csv::Reader::from_path("foo.csv")?;
    for result in rdr.deserialize() {
            let record: Record = result?;
           let x0= match record.Time{
                Some(x)=> x,
                None=> 0.0,
            };
            ...
     }
    Ok(())
}
fn main() {
    if let Err(err) = example() {
        println!("error running example: {}", err);
        process::exit(1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [csv](https://crates.io/crates/csv) crate, which has a custom deserializer: `csv::invalid_option`.
Then you can use a macro like this in your struct:

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
struct Record {
    Time: Option<f32>,
    #[serde(deserialize_with = "csv::invalid_option")]
    Ampl:Option<f32>,
}
```

to have invalid data converted to None values